# Javascript regular expression for currency format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have this regular expression `/^\d(\d|\,\d{3}|,\d.+$)*$/`

With my sample data:

```
100.00 - Not working :(
1,000.00 - Working
100,000.00 - Working
1,000,000.00 - Working
```

Note: I need to give error if result is **0.00**

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What should be your output for `100.00`...??

Comment: Hi Prasath. I am using above regular expression for my project and when user type 100.00 and not working.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could perhaps use:

```
^(?!0\.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$
```

See how it's working [here](https://regex101.com/r/hL2pF2/1).

Additionally, if you'd like to forbid leading zeros the regex would be:

```
^(?!0\.00)[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$
```

Comment: The top solution, with the link to regex101.com, passes for `00.7`, which seems incorrect to me

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Hm, I don't know how, but the regex101 link is wrong. I think that website has some url changed. You can see the regex is not the same. Gonna fix that.

Comment: This solution will only pass if commas exist. For example: `123123.45` will fail. `123.45` will pass. `123,123.45` will pass.

Comment: @MattWagner what you mentioned is not  the requirement per the OP

Comment: @Jerry This is an old answer that I found in searching for my solution and wanted to add to it so that others who happen upon will also see that it fails for any missing comma if there should be one. No downvote, just a comment.

Comment: @MattWagner then I believe this is not the answer you are looking for. StackOverflow has specific questions and specific answers to them. I can add the one you are asking for in the answer, but then it wouldn't answer the question I'm answering to anymore... If you cannot find a question that fits your situation, I suggest you create a new question saying that this answer here only partly addresses the problem. I can provide a new answer in that case if you want me to.

Comment: Different *countries* have [different currency number systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator). This answer will only work for some.

Comment: And I'm fine with it. This answer was not meant to be a solution that fits all, but a solution that fits the question being asked... What's more, some countries use either depending on the situation, so it's just not realistic to have a one solution that fits all in a single post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
^\$?(?!0.00)(([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*)[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

It will check

100.00 - yes

1,000.00 - yes

100,000.00 - yes

1,000,000.00 - yes

0.00 - no

Answer (score 0):

A symbol version

```
^([^\d\s]{1,}\s?[+-]?)(\d{1,3})(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,})?$
```

Will check

- 100 - NO
- 1,000.00 - NO
- & -100,000.00 - YES
- ¥ -1,000,000.00 - YES
- € 1.000 - YES
- € 100,000,00.7 - NO
- $ 0.00 - YES
- R$ 1,000.00 - YES