# RegEx for currency (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I am new to regular expressions and i would like to validate user input with javascript.

The user input is a currency, but i want it without the thousands commata.

**Valid**

```
"12.34"
"12,34"
"1234,5"
"123"
"123,00"
"12000"
```

**Invalid**

```
"12a34"
"abc"
"12.000,00"
"12,000.00"
```

I tried the following regex-pattern, but it doesnt work for me. it validates for example "12a34" and i dont know why.

```
/\d+([\.|\,]\d+)?/
```

What would be the correct regex-pattern ? Could you explain this step by step ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regular expression for currency format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205377/javascript-regular-expression-for-currency-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not escape the `.` while in a character group. Try with following regex:

```
/^\d+([.,]\d{1,2})?$/

^   = start of string
$   = end of string
()? = an optional capturegroup ( e.g. to validate "123")
{x,y} = The symbol may occur minimum x and maximum y times
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. What does the ^ and the $ mean for this pattern ?

Comment: `^` means that you are matching regex from the first character of the string and `$` to the end. Without it, regex can match just a part of the string.

Comment: +1 just to mention that if you want to match up to 2 digits after the decimal point you can use `\d{1,2}` instead of `\d+`

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, really helps me understanding regex!

Answer (score -1):

```
RegExp: /^(?!\(.*[^)]$|[^(].*\)$)\(?\$?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)(\.\d\d?)?\)?$/g
pattern: ^(?!\(.*[^)]$|[^(].*\)$)\(?\$?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)(\.\d\d?)?\)?$
flags: g
3 capturing groups: 
   group 1: (0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?)
   group 2: (,?\d{3})
   group 3: (\.\d\d?)
```

[Regex Test](http://regexr.com?3797b)

Comment: Links rot - and then your answer is useless.

Comment: In other words, give an answer _here_. You can _also_ provide a link to a fiddle or test site, but that other site is not going to be around forever. Answers (and examples and questions as well!) should be self-contained.